# Variable types when converting python to cython

Tags: python, c, performance, cython

I am working in Python with a recursive loop that calculates the first passage time to point L of a random walk.
I've written the code but i want to optimise it by converting it to Cython but i have no experience with C, and i have no idea how to convert this code to be suitable for optimisation, or how to describe variable types. Any help would be appreciated.

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def f_passagetime_rec_cython(L,start=[0,0]):


    T=10000000
    r = np.zeros((T,2))
    r[0]=start
    delta = 1
    greater=False
    for i in range (0,T - 1):
        if r[i,0]<=L:
            theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size = None)
            r[i + 1,0] = r[i,0] + np.cos(theta)*delta                
            r[i + 1,1] = r[i,1] + np.sin(theta)*delta
        else:
            greater=True
            return i


    if greater==False:
        x=f_passagetime_rec_cython(L,r[-1])
        i=x+1+i

    return i
```

Comment: @MoShaikG It does

Comment: @MoShaikG do you know how i would assign data types to the variables in the code?

Comment: you can prepend variable types before variable names for example: T=10000000 becomes cdef int T=10000000 (where int is the basic c/cpp type)

Comment: @MoShaikG do you have any idea how i would optimise this code in cython
```
for i in range (0,T - 1):
        if r[i,0]<=L:
            theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size = None)
            r[i + 1,0] = r[i,0] + np.cos(theta)*delta                
            r[i + 1,1] = r[i,1] + np.sin(theta)*delta
        else:
            greater=True
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would suggest cythonizing. Create a `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("function.pyx")
)
```

Then your `function.pyx` file is basically your python code:

```
import numpy as np

def f_passagetime_rec_cython(L,start=[0,0]):


    T=10000000
    r = np.zeros((T,2))
    r[0]=start
    delta = 1
    greater=False
    for i in range (0,T - 1):
        if r[i,0]<=L:
            theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size = None)
            r[i + 1,0] = r[i,0] + np.cos(theta)*delta                
            r[i + 1,1] = r[i,1] + np.sin(theta)*delta
        else:
            greater=True
            return i


    if greater==False:
        x=f_passagetime_rec_cython(L,r[-1])
        i=x+1+i

    return i
```

Then build the cythonised function in terminal as follows:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

You can access the cythonised function by importing using standard Python syntax:

```
import function
function.f_passagetime_rec_cython(10)
```